# Blog sub-domain using existing database - Wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, subdomain, blogs

I have wordpress website like `example.com` and my current blog as follow `example.com/blog`, Now I want to move subdomain as `blog.example.com` also wordpress, There is anyway to fetching 'Posts' data on my `blog.example.com`? If possible how I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to create multisite in wordpress.

create a multisite in your existing wordpress and setup a new site named blog

Comment: Can you explain this?

Comment: add me on your skype. rajkumar.gaur.91@gmail.com